# Magento Errors limit (100) reached. How to increase limit?

Tags: php, magento, import, limit

I am getting an error on my upload file for magento.

Product Type is invalid or not supported in rows: 8473, 8474, 8475, 8476, 8477, 8478, 8479, 8494, 8495, 8496, 8497, 8515, 8516, 8517, 8518, 8519, 8520, 8521, 8522, 8552, 8553, 8559, 8562....

Errors limit (100) reached. Please fix errors and re-upload file

is there a way to increase the errors limit to output 10,000? that way i can easily remove the rows which are giving me problems on excel.  How do i increase the error limit?

Answer (score 5):

The error limit is hardcoded in the following class:

```
app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Abstract.php
```

on the following line:

```
protected $_errorsLimit = 100;
```

So either find a way to overload the class and somehow inject it to the Import Controller located here:

```
app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/controllers/Adminhtml/ImportController.php
```

Or just hack it if you need some quick solution to find the failing rows. And don't forget to revert it, as messing with magento core is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

David, you should check if the categories of the imported products are already in the backend. Once you get them on the CMS the errors will disappear. Also check if the values for attributes set column are created on the CMS.

I hope it helps.